# Can't get navbar "brand" down

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, erb

I've looked on multiple sites to try and figure out why my "brand" is up so high on my navbar and can't figure it out. I'm making a ripoff of Pinterest just for practice. Plz don't laugh.

[image: https://a.disquscdn.com/uploads/mediaembed/images/766/947/original.jpg]

Here is the code. 
    @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700);

```
$body-bg:                                                   #ecf0f1;
$font-family-sans-serif:                'Lato', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial,         sans-serif;
$navbar-height:                                        25px;
$navbar-default-bg:                          white;
$navbar-default-brand-color:      #c0392b;
$brand-primary:                                    #c0392b;
$jumbotron-bg:                                         white;

@import 'bootstrap';

.center {
 text-align: center;
}

.navbar-brand {
 font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Has it got a `float: left;`? Maybe add some code to see exactly problem.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked in the stylesheets to make sure you're applying the right styling?

try doing ctrl shift i, and inspect the element.

I don't know how you constructed your logo, whether it's wrapped in div tags, if it's a list item, etc. Need more info.

some CSS attributes you might want to consider using:
vertial-align
line-height (for list items)
position (absolute / relative) if wrapped in a div.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your stylesheets, but it looks to me like both your brand and your navigation elements (Home About) are spanning the entire length of your header, so they are stacking on top of each other.

A rough solution, without knowing what your current stylesheet looks like, could be something like this:

```
.brand {
    float: left;
    width: [some explicit width];
}

.nav {
    float: right;
    width: [some explicit width];
}
```

By defining the width and floating the elements they shouldn't stack on top of each other like they are now.  You should try using the Chrome's built in developer tools to see how the elements are displayed on the page, I would bet that your brand's and navigation's bounding boxes will both span the entire length of the header. I find this helps a lot when I run into situations like yours when I am trying to position elements.

Alternatively you could use Bootstrap's built in rows to set up your structure,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4">[brand here]</div>
    <div class="span4"></div>
    <div class="span4">[nav here]</div>
</div>
```

The Twitter Bootstrap documentation has any answers you should need about specific questions regarding this method: 
http://getbootstrap.com

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

HOPE THIS WILL HELP YOU.

```
<div class="navbar">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a
        <a class="brand" href="#" name="top">Brand Name</a>

            <ul class="nav pull-right">

                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-wrench"></i> HOME</a></li>
                    <li class="divider"></li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="icon-share"></i>ABOUT</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```